# How to Get ID Lexer from code that has tokenize in ANTLR

Tags: parsing, antlr, token, lexer

I have a lexer class that determined the token ID Lexer. The code is :

```
public class Antlr3JavaLexer extends Lexer {
public static final int PACKAGE=84;
public static final int PUBLIC=87;
public static final int STATIC=90;
public static final int IDENT=164;
public static final int CLASS = 70;  
}
```

Now I have a java class named hello.java that will be generated by ANTLR. The code is like this 
`public class hello{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.print("Hello World");}
    }`

now, time to ANTLR lexer that i created get shot..

```
BufferedReader in = null;
try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mainFile.getAbsolutePath())); // Assumption this is to read the hello.class
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    final Antlr3JavaLexer lexer = new Antlr3JavaLexer();

    try {
        lexer.setCharStream(new ANTLRReaderStream(in));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // return false;
    }

    final CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream();
    tokens.setTokenSource(lexer);

    Antlr3JavaParser parser = new Antlr3JavaParser(tokens); 
    System.out.println(tokens + "and" + "\n"); //First Print
    System.out.println(tokens.getTokens); // Second Print
```

Lucky, I get the output like this :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tsogz10eouo9f9h/ID%20Token.bmp

So, the question is :
How can I get the ID from the tokens?. For example `public class hello` is
`public` = 87, 
`class`  = 70,
`hello` is identifier = 164.
SO, perhaps the output like this

```
8770164
```

Thanks 4 the help...

Comment: Mr. Bart Kiers, any idea ?

Comment: I dont know how to modify getTokens in the class CommonTokenStream, please help

Answer (score 1):

When you append an object to a `StringBuilder` (or `StringBuffer`, which you should probably not be using), it calls `ToString()` on the object and appends the resulting text. If you want to format the list in another way, you'll need to iterate over the elements and append the text in the desired format.

In this case, the desired format appears to be `Token.getType()`.

```
boolean first = true;
for (Token token : tokens.getTokens()) {
  if (first) {
    first = false;
  } else {
    sb.append(", ");
  }

  sb.append(token.getType());
}
```

Comment: @FadlyMassere `CommonTokenStream` is not a token. Why would it implement the `Token.getType()` method? It's really unclear what you are looking for with this question.

Comment: Mr 280Z28, Token can not be converted to Object. SO, the looping is not possible. Any suggestion ? You are life saver..

Comment: @FadlyMassere Everything can be converted to Object in Java. You're going to have to post a complete working project for us to compile and run if you want further help. No one understands your questions as they are currently written.

Comment: have you an email @ Mr. 280Z28, I will sent to you my project